# dyld: Library not loaded: on OS X

Tags: c++, macos, dyld

I'm building with g++ from the command line in OS X, and not using XCode.  When I built my executable I had to include the linker flag to the library where the dynamic library was stored, but when I went to run the executable the dynamic library was not found, and I got the error `dyld: Library not loaded: (foo)`.

There were a few questions on here already about dynamic libraries related to specific software packages and how to get dynamic libraries built into XCode projects, but nothing generic explaining how Mac OS X looks for dynamic libraries in general and how to get a new .dylib into the search path for the executable.

Could someone fill in that gap.  How does Mac OS X look for dynamic libraries when one is built with an executable and how would I put a link to my dynamic library in the right place so the executable will run?

I'm on OSX 10.9 - Mavericks.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10359063/dyld-library-not-loaded-opt-local-lib-libglib-2-0-0-dylib?rq=1 and the Apple topic referenced in its answer: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/DynamicLibraries/000-Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A good place to start would be the Apple documentation on [Dynamic Library Programming Topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/DynamicLibraries/100-Articles/OverviewOfDynamicLibraries.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001873-SW1)
and especially [Run-Path Dependent Libraries](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/DynamicLibraries/100-Articles/RunpathDependentLibraries.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008306-SW1).

"When the dynamic loader (dyld) loads the executable, it looks for run-path dependent libraries in the run-path search paths in the order in which they were specified at link time."

The first think is to check the libraries dependencies for you binary using otool:

```
otool -L /path/to/binary
```

Then, you have different solutions depending on how you want to distribute your library.

You can specify the absolute path of the library in the binary. It should be done with a tool, CMake for instance. Otherwise, you can use

```
install_name_tool to change the path to a library by hand.
```

Most of the time, you want to deploy your binary and put the dylibs in a separated folder. Those libraries are loaded relatively to where the binary is.
For example:

```
    @loader_path/../Frameworks/Sparkle.framework/Versions/A/Sparkle
```

For more info about paths, I suggest you read [this blog](https://wincent.com/wiki/@executable_path,_@load_path_and_@rpath).

Comment: I appreciate the link to the article on Dynamic Library Programming Topics.  What's the difference between `install_name_tool` and what I ended up doing which was to manually build a sym link to the library in the `/usr/local/lib/` folder?

Comment: The path to the library is written in itself, that's why you should never move a dylib once it is installed. Doing a symlink is juste cheating the linker because your dylib has an path issue. It works but it is a hack. You could add your lib folder to the corresponding environnement variable though. Check this link http://superuser.com/questions/282450/where-do-i-set-dyld-library-path-on-mac-os-x-and-is-it-a-good-idea